# Why does my autoencoder for de-noising in PyTorch learns to zero out everything?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder

I need to build a de-noising autoencoder using pytorch for the task of cleaning out signals.

For example, I can take the `cosine` function and sample it in intervals (where i have two parameters - `B` and `K`. `B` is the number of intervals I take in each example and `K` is how many sampling points (equally distanced) are in each interval) so for instance, I can take `B = 5` intervals and measure `K = 8` points in each interval. Hence the distance between each point is `2pi / 8` and i have a total of `40` points. The number of functions I try to generalize is `L` and I treat this like different channels. Then I add a random starting position for each example (to make it slightly different) then random noise and send it to the autoencoder to train.

The thing is, no matter what architecture or learning rate, gradually it learns to output nothing but zeros. The autoencoder is super simple so I dont reckon there's a problem with it but rather a problem of how I generate my data.

I attach both of the codes anyways:

```
class ConvAutoencoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, enc_channels, dec_channels):
    super(ConvAutoencoder, self).__init__()
    ## encoder layers ##

    encoder_layers = []
    decoder_layers = []

    in_channels = enc_channels[0]

    for i in range(1, len(enc_channels)):
        out_channels = enc_channels[i]

        encoder_layers += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, bias=True),
                           nn.ReLU()]
        in_channels = out_channels

    in_channels = dec_channels[0]

    for i in range(1, len(dec_channels)):
        out_channels = dec_channels[i]

        decoder_layers += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, bias=True),
                           nn.ReLU()]
        in_channels = out_channels


    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(*encoder_layers)
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(*decoder_layers)


def forward(self, x):

    if len(x.shape) == 3:
        x = x.unsqueeze(dim=-1)

    res = self.decoder(self.encoder(x)).squeeze(-1)

    return res
```

And the data generation is as follows:

```
def generate_data(batch_size: int, intervals: int, sample_length: int, channels_functions, noise_scale=1)->torch.tensor:
    channels = len(channels_functions)
    mul_term = 2 * np.pi / sample_length # each sample is 2pi and equally distance
    
    # each example is K * B long
    positions = np.arange(0, sample_length * intervals)
    x = positions * mul_term

    # creating random start points (from negative to positive)
    random_starting_pos = (np.random.rand(batch_size) - 0.5) * 10000
    start_pos_mat = np.tile(random_starting_pos , (sample_length * intervals, 1))
    start_pos_mat = np.tile(start_pos_mat , (channels, 1)).T
    start_pos_mat = np.reshape(start_pos_mat , (batch_size, channels, sample_length * intervals))

    X = np.tile(x, (channels, 1))
    X = np.repeat(X[np.newaxis, :, :], batch_size, axis=0)

    X += start_pos_mat #adding the random starting position

    # apply each function to a different channel
    for i, function in enumerate(channels_functions):
        X[:, i, :] = function(X[:, i, :])

    clean = X
    noise = np.random.normal(scale=noise_scale, size=clean.shape)
    noisy = clean + noise

    # normalizing each sample
    row_sums = np.linalg.norm(clean, axis=2)
    clean = clean / row_sums[:, :, np.newaxis]
    row_sums = np.linalg.norm(noisy, axis=2)
    noisy = noisy / row_sums[:, :, np.newaxis]

    clean = torch.from_numpy(clean)
    noisy = torch.from_numpy(noisy)

    return clean, noisy
```

Edit - Added the entire training loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

func_list = [lambda x: np.cos(x),
             lambda x: np.cos((x**4) / 10),
             lambda x: np.sin(x**3 * np.cos(x**2)),
             lambda x: 0.25*np.cos(x**2) - 10*np.sin(0.25*x)]

L = len(func_list)
K = 3
B = 4

enc_channels = [L, 64, 128, 256]


num_epochs = 100

model = models.ConvAutoencoder(enc_channels, enc_channels[::-1])

criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.005, weight_decay=1e-5)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    clean, noisy = util.generate_data(128, K, B, func_list)

    # ===================forward=====================
    output = model(noisy.float())
    loss = criterion(output.float(), clean.float())
    # ===================backward====================
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    # ===================log========================
    print('epoch [{}/{}], loss:{:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, loss.data))

    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        show_clean, show_noisy = util.generate_data(1, K, B, func_list)
        print("clean\n{}".format(show_clean))
        print("noisy\n{}".format(show_noisy))
        print("denoised\n{}".format(model(show_noisy.float())))
```

sure enough after like 10 epochs the model outputs:

```
clean vector
tensor([[[ 0.3611, -0.1905, -0.3611,  0.1905,  0.3611, -0.1905, -0.3611,
           0.1905,  0.3611, -0.1905, -0.3611,  0.1905],
         [ 0.3387, -0.0575, -0.2506, -0.3531, -0.3035,  0.3451,  0.3537,
          -0.2416,  0.2652, -0.3126, -0.3203, -0.1707],
         [-0.0369,  0.4412, -0.1323,  0.1802, -0.2943,  0.3590,  0.4549,
           0.0827, -0.0164,  0.4350, -0.1413, -0.3395],
         [ 0.3997,  0.3516,  0.2451,  0.1136, -0.0458, -0.1944, -0.3225,
          -0.3925, -0.3971, -0.3382, -0.2457, -0.1153]]], dtype=torch.float64)
noisy vector
tensor([[[-0.1071, -0.0671,  0.0993, -0.2029,  0.1587, -0.4407, -0.0867,
          -0.2598,  0.2426, -0.6939, -0.3011, -0.0870],
         [ 0.0889, -0.3415, -0.1434, -0.2393, -0.4708,  0.0144,  0.2620,
          -0.1186,  0.6424,  0.0886, -0.2192, -0.1562],
         [ 0.1989,  0.2794,  0.0848, -0.2729, -0.2168,  0.1475,  0.5294,
           0.4788,  0.1754,  0.2333, -0.0549, -0.3665],
         [ 0.3611,  0.3535,  0.1957,  0.1980, -0.1115, -0.1912, -0.2713,
          -0.4087, -0.3669, -0.3675, -0.2991, -0.1356]]], dtype=torch.float64)
denoised vector
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you also post the code of your training pipeline?

Comment: Could you try training the model with more trivial data(the ones that are harder to mistake with)? That way, you may find out whether the data is actually the problem.

Comment: Why are you using binary cross entropy as your loss? Try using the L2 loss.

Comment: Also when using the BCELoss, your outputs should be between 0 and 1, so you should use a sigmoid in your final layer. Alternatively (and better) you can use no activation function in your final layer and instead use the BCEWithLogitsLoss (https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html).

Comment: L2 was my goto but it yielded the same result

Comment: What kind of data with the same structure would you consider trivial? Like a constant 1s with some noise?

Comment: @YarinBar Yes, things like that. Or else you could try to make the model to learn some polynomials. Also, please use the notifying feature with @.

Comment: @tritsu I changed it to L2 loss and removed the ReLU as suggested by other users and it did in fact helped a bit with the trivial examples i tried (like constant or f(x)=x) but for some reason whenever i try to denoise something cosine or sin it just goes but to zeroing out everything (after said changed it happens much slower though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a ReLU in the final layer, however your target (clean) contains negative values. When you are using a ReLU in your final layer, you cannot obtain negative values.

Simply replace your decoder with this:

```
    for i in range(1, len(dec_channels)):
        out_channels = dec_channels[i]
        
        if i == len(dec_channels) - 1:
            # last layer
            decoder_layers += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, bias=True)]
        else:
            decoder_layers += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, bias=True),
                               nn.ReLU()]
        in_channels = out_channels
```

And then I would suggest using the L2 loss.

Comment: I tried this and it helped to slow down the zeroing out but didnt prevent it. Maybe there is something to do with the data generation that makes it do that?

Comment: I will also add that it seems like regardless of the input signal and the function im trying to generalize, it always outputs a matrix with a same value for all entries